# xUnit-cli can't find dotnet on MacOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xunit.net, xunit2

I have a Xamarin forms project that I'm running on an Intel Mac. We are using XUnit for unit testing, and I would like to be able to run the tests on the command line on my Mac. The tests run inside the IDE but I can't get them to run on the command line. I have tried many different options and nothing seems to work. The current way I'm trying to get the tests to run is by using the [XUnit cli](https://github.com/natemcmaster/xunit-cli) tool.

I have dotnet installed and on my path, running
`dotnet --version`
returns
`6.0.110`

I installed xunit-cli with the following command
`dotnet tool install -g xunit-cli`

and I've added xunit on my path, however, when I run the xunit-cli I get the following error

```
You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /Users/luke/.dotnet/tools/xunit
Architecture: x64
App host version: 6.0.10
.NET location: Not found

Learn about runtime installation:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

Download the .NET runtime:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=x64&rid=osx.13-x64&apphost_version=6.0.10
```

What part of my setup is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use xunit-cli?

You can simply install the `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` NuGet package in your test project and use `dotnet test` instead:

```
dotnet test MyProject.csproj
```

Comment: I've tried that and I get the following error
```Testhost process exited with error: Cannot open assembly '/usr/local/Cellar/dotnet/6.0.110/libexec/sdk/6.0.110/Extensions/..//TestHost/testhost.net472.x86.exe': No such file or directory.
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.```
I've also tried with the `-f netstandard2.0` option and `-f netcoreapp3.1` and they don't work either

Comment: You test project is targeting which target framework?